# unit test logical remove, eclipselink does not make a new request

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, eclipselink

I explain my problem:

I created a unit test in java with junit the **spring data framework** and **JPA** with **eclipselink** and **HSQL**.Then I make a **findOne** to retrieve a given element

I make a logical removal (set removed = 1 + save) of an element by its ID which is in the database.

Then I make a **findOne** of the element to verify that it no longer exists but spring data returns it to me anyway.

I use @AdditionalCriteria annotation ("this.removed = 0") to filter logically deleted objects.

It seems that for the second findOne, eclipselink does not make a new request. **So my question is how to force him to redo a request?**

here is the code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/test/resources/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @WithUserDetails(value = "user")
    public void testDeleteEvent() {
        Object event = repository.findOne(123);
        repository.delete(123);
        event = repository.findOne(123);
        assertTrue(event == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: 1. Tests with DB usually aren't called unit. 2. What is your setup of transaction in this test? 3. As @JBNizet said — post your code,

Comment: sorry , I update the code see about

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--

Comment: thanks you, i try to use it